# Image not centered when larger than viewport

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

When the viewport is larger than the width of the image, the image is centered, but when the width of the image is larger than the width of the viewport, the image is aligned to the left rather than to the center. The effect I am aiming for is for the image to always be cropped to the width of the viewport and always be aligned to the center.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.crop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

#cropped-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img id="cropped-img" src="http://img1.jurko.net/wall/paper/donald_duck_4.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed to get the exact effect I needed using the background-image property. Here is the HTML and CSS I used if anyone else is interested:

HTML:

```
<div class="crop"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.crop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("http://img1.jurko.net/wall/paper/donald_duck_4.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with flexbox:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.crop {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img id="cropped-img" src="http://img1.jurko.net/wall/paper/donald_duck_4.jpg" >
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. In the end I just ended up using background-image with background-repeat: no-repeat and background-position: center though, as it was much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Try giving variable values ​​the image that occupy 100% of width of the element

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.crop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#cropped-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img id="cropped-img" src="http://img1.jurko.net/wall/paper/donald_duck_4.jpg" />
</div>
```